# SQL Server 2008 Agent keep stopping for unknown reason

Tags: sql-server, sqldump

My MSSQL 2008 service keep stopping don't know why. I took the habit to just restart the service, but it's getting really annoying.

Does anyone has a clue on why it keeps shutting down ?

Sql server 2008, logged as local.

Here are 4 SQLdump from today.

[09:29:36 09/28/16](http://pastebin.com/4AH2Mrad)

[10:05:42 09/28/16](http://pastebin.com/V8Xs4y58)

[10:32:18 09/28/16](http://pastebin.com/PaPRmmeK)

[10:46:14 09/28/16](http://pastebin.com/aTz1aQzu)

found this in my event viewer :

> SQL Server is terminating because of fatal exception c0000005. This error may be caused by an unhandled Win32 or C++ exception, or by an access violation encountered during exception handling. Check the SQL error log for any related stack dumps or messages. This exception forces SQL Server to shutdown. To recover from this error, restart the server (unless SQLAgent is configured to auto restart).

Error when I tried to install MSSQL 2008 SP3 (x64)

> The version of the instance of SQL Server Shared Component does not match the expected version of the update to SQL Server. The version of the SQL Server product installed is 10.50.1600.1 and the version of SQL Server expected is 10.0.1600.22.

`SELECT @@VERSION` res

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
>       Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
>       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>       Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )

Comment: Looks like you are on 2008 R2 RTM. I would suggest updating to SP3. Not that this is necessarily the issue but it could be.

Comment: Can you please share `SELECT @@VERSION` result?

Comment: That info is in the log files: 10.50.1600.1  Windows NT 6.2 Build 9200 CSD

Comment: @BobKlimes updated question to include error I got when installing SP3

Comment: From the error it looks like you have 2008 r2 installed and not 2008.  The info that @RajeshRanjan asked for would be useful for the sp install failure

Comment: @Aaron i updated

Comment: @plaudet you tried installing SP from 2008, here is link for sp3 for 2008 R2 https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=44271

Comment: @BobKlimes it seems to have worked ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PLAudet great. I added that as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation is on RTM of SQL Server 2008 R2. Try upgrading to currently supported Service Pack 3 https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=44271